# Illustrating Sorting Process of Balls In Unity Using Sorting Algorithms

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine, swap

I want to illustrate the process of sorting by two by two replacing balls. Like in this image;[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VufsU.png) but with [Balls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV5XQ.png), can you help me to do it?

There should be some delay inside the loop for Illustrating the process but I couldn't make it properly and when I click the sort button the Unity frezees.

After randomizing the faces of the [randomized balls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVcMO.png) are  5 3 2 4 1 so it should sort 5 - 3 and show that sorting then sort 2 - 5 then 4 - 5 so that replacing needs to be illustrated.

I have other sorting algorithms such as Selection and Bubble but I can do them myself I suppose if I can get answer to this one.

[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6kpH.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


namespace Assets
{
    class Gameobjects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Button s_YourButton;
        [SerializeField]

        public GameObject[] Balls = new GameObject[5];


        public GameObject[] instantiatedObjects= new GameObject[5];

        void Start()
        {
            Button btn = s_YourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            //Calls the TaskOnClick method when you click the Button
            btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
            Balls[0] = GameObject.Find("5");
            Balls[1] = GameObject.Find("3");
            Balls[2] = GameObject.Find("2");
            Balls[3] = GameObject.Find("4");
            Balls[4] = GameObject.Find("1");
        }
        List<Vector3> vectorList = new List<Vector3>();

        void Update()
        {
            performInsertionSort(instantiatedObjects); 
        }
        void TaskOnClick()
        {
            Fill();
            //instantiatedObjects = instantiatedObjects.OrderBy(go => go.name).ToList();
            //performInsertionSort(instantiatedObjects);
            //for (int i = 0; i < instantiatedObjects.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    instantiatedObjects[i].transform.position = vectorList[i];
            //}
            string name = "1";
            string name1 = "2";
            string name2 = "3";
            string name3 = "4";
            string name4 = "5";

            GameObject go1 = GameObject.Find(name);
            GameObject go2 = GameObject.Find(name1);
            GameObject go3 = GameObject.Find(name2);
            GameObject go4 = GameObject.Find(name3);
            GameObject go5 = GameObject.Find(name4);
            //if the tree exist then destroy it
            if (go1 & go2 & go3 & go4 & go5)
            {
                Destroy(go1.gameObject);
                Destroy(go2.gameObject);
                Destroy(go3.gameObject);
                Destroy(go4.gameObject);
                Destroy(go5.gameObject);

            }
        }

        private void performInsertionSort(GameObject[] instantiatedObjects)
        {
            {
                int k = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < instantiatedObjects.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    int j = i + 1;

                    while (j > 0)
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(instantiatedObjects[j - 1].name, instantiatedObjects[j].name) > 0)
                        {
                            GameObject temp = instantiatedObjects[j - 1];
                            instantiatedObjects[j - 1] = instantiatedObjects[j];
                            instantiatedObjects[j] = temp;

                            while (k < instantiatedObjects.Length){

                                instantiatedObjects[k].transform.position = vectorList[k];
                        }
                            k++; 

                        }

                        j--;

                    }
                    StartCoroutine(Example());
                }
            }
        }
        IEnumerator Example()
        {
            print(Time.time);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            print(Time.time);
        }

public void Fill()
{
    vectorList.Clear();
    instantiatedObjects = new GameObject[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < Balls.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject spawnedObject = Instantiate(Balls[i]) as GameObject;
        instantiatedObjects[i] = spawnedObject ;
        vectorList.Add(spawnedObject.transform.position);
    }
}
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont put your `performInsertionSort` method in `Update` because you dont want it to be called each frame. you can call it on `Start` if it should be called just once

Comment: Seems like it but still like this it doesnt even sort. It was working when I put `instantiatedObjects[k].transform.position = vectorList[k];` with [j] instead of k and without while but it but the last ball did not move and I couldn't Illustrate 2 by 2.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/udiprod)

Comment: I need to do something like those but more simplier, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

you have many mistakes in your code

**First one :** Is that you shouldn't write

```
                `for (int i = 0; i < instantiatedObjects.Length - 1; i++)`
```

instead write

```
                for (int i = 0; i < instantiatedObjects.Length; i++)
```

without `-1` Beacuse length starts counting from 1 so if you have five elements in the array it will return 5 and the loop will be done for 5 times so if you want to add `-1` you should type

```
                    for (int i = 0; i <= instantiatedObjects.Length - 1; i++)
```

with equal or less than sign(<=)

**Second one :** that you shouldn't type `While j > 0`
Beacause it is considered as infinite loop J = 0 + 1 so j > 0 
it will does all the code inside the while loop the checks if j still bigger than zero or not then does all the code again and again that's why unity freezes
example for infinite loop is :

```
int x = 0;
while(1 > 0)
{
    x++;
}
```

it never goes of those 2 brackets because it is an infinite loop
example for finite loop :

```
int x = 0;
while(x < 10)
{
    x++
}
```

it is a finite loop because after 11 loops x will be equal to 11 and 11 is greater than 10 so it goes to the rest of the code in your script

**third one** You should type `StartCoroutine(Example());` at the start of your function.

**fourth one** is you should call the function inside `fixedUpdate` instead of `Update` Because it has a corutine called inside it and it's always better to use `start()` to sort just one Because if you used `fixedupdte` it will sort it one time then it will check it again and again without end